# LWP upload direct from form field

Tags: perl, upload, lwp

I am trying to get LWP to upload a file selected in a file-field of a form.

```
<input type ="file"  name="file">
```

I select a file called testfile.xml for example, submit the form to script which parses the form data using

```
my $filename = $query->upload("file");
```

and correctly gives the result "testfile.xml"

This value uploads just fine using cgi.pm however I cannot use that for this project, and using LWP I am unable to get the module to accept the file.

Many examples that promise to do this on the web do not work, or no longer work. For example -

```
my $req = $browser=> POST('https://myserver.com/abc/',
Content_Type => 'form-data',
Content => [ id => "123",
var => "var1",
file => [$filename],
]);
```

The above snippet produces

```
"Can't open file testfile.xml: No such file or directory", i.e. the path is not being read.
```

If a path is supplied  as below

```
my $req = $browser=> POST('https://myserver.com/abc/',
Content_Type => 'form-data',
Content => [ id => "$id",
regexp => "$regex",
file => [/home/html/files/$filename],
]);
```

then LWP uploads and all is fine so I know all else is working, but the users of this form will be selecting files from anywhere on the hard drives so the path cannot be a fixed value.

So the question is does anyone know how to select a local file using a file field in an html form, submit the form and pass it correctly to LWP to upload, without uploading to a temp folder first?

Have spent a good few hours on this and am close to finding a tall building so any help on taming LWP would be much appreciated!!

Many thanks :-)

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. You have a server with an upload form, and the uploaded file should then be uploaded by LWP to somewhere else?

Comment: I'm with bytepusher, I don't quite get what you're trying to do here. LWP is not a replacement for CGI.pm. LWP is for writing web *clients*; CGI is for handling requests on web *servers*. Please clarify which of these you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi guys, to answer a few queries.  Yes a server with an upload form and then I have to send an http request to a third-party API with the file selected which then responds with a JSON formatted reply.  It's quite common practice with plain data but I'm surprised there is no easy way to do this with a file.  It seems it used to work but browser security means now that there is no path sent along with the form submission.

Comment: Are you saying the file is already on the web server?

Comment: Hi,The file is selected via a web form on my server. The file will be on whichever computer the user is using when viewing that form.  If this were straight cgi.pm then the resulting upload would be fine, but the purpose is not to upload it to my server, but to grab the file contents and upload it via http request to the server-endpoint on a third party webserver. To have to first upload it to a temp file on my server before being able to send it via http request is just plain daft, will take twice as long and thus twice the risk of the transfer failing, so any suggestions welcomed!

Comment: There's no way to send a file from your server to another server without having the file.

Comment: Hi, I'm beginning to think the same however, the location of the form is actually immaterial, it could equally be on the same server as the JSON script, what the issue is is that this used to work but now does not.  See here http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch05_07.htm, the "saywhat" value is taken in from a webform, the file is then streamed directly using LWP. Shame it no longer works. Thank you kindly for your time and input :-)

Comment: You're misunderstanding that page. It shows how to use LWP::UserAgent to upload a file from your local machine to a remote host, without having to manually fill in an HTML form in a browser. It does *not* show how to upload a file from one remote machine to another remote machine using code on your local machine.

Comment: Hi, no I think you've misunderstood what I'm trying to do. "how to use LWP::UserAgent to upload a file from your local machine to a remote host", is exactly what I need, and no it's not "without having to manually fill in an HTML form in a browser" you should read it again. The input is from a form, the explanation of how it works only makes it look like a manual entry. Sadly the example no longer works and as mentioned previously the reason is browser changes.

Comment: The example works (I just tested it), and has nothing to do with browser changes because there's no browser involved. There's a file upload form on a remote website; most users would navigate to `http://www.example.com/upload` in their browser, pick the file they want to upload, and click submit. You, being a savvy Perl hacker, don't want to go to all that trouble, so you whip up some code that uses LWP::UserAgent to submit the form for you, without ever opening a browser. This is what the example is about, and if you read the previous chapter in the book you linked to, that will be clearer.

Comment: Ok understood - thanks for the explanation and the time you have spent on this, much appreciated.  Have marked your comments as useful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
$filename
```

contain only the file name, not the absolute path for the submitted file. Try this:

```
my $file_absolute_path = $query->param("file");
```

and send the request as:

```
my $req = $browser=> POST('https://myserver.com/abc/',
Content_Type => 'form-data',
Content => [ id => "123",
var => "var1",
file => [$file_absolute_path],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but sadly this does not work - I see where your logic is though.  Changing the above param produces same response as before.